# Layer filter in viewport

Tags: qgis, layers, zoom, geometries

Is there a way to display the geometries in the "Layer" viewport, so that you can zoom to the geometry in question with a right click. I only know the categorized view via the layer design. But then I can only access the layer design in the viewport "Layer" but not the geometry itself.

In the end it should be similar to the display in GoogleEarth Pro. Where I can select all geometries individually.

[image]

Comment: Split your data into a single layer for each feature, then you can zoom to the layers.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I have in my head. 

What I'm trying to achieve exactly is that the geometries of a layer are displayed in the layer view window and I don't have to go through the attribute table first. However, splitting the layer into separate layers is not a solution....

Answer (score 2):

Open the attribute table then :

1. switch to form view
2. select the appropriate column to display the feature name (or set an
   expression)
3. activate zoom (or pan if desired) to current feature
4. Set the "Highlight current feature on map" to your desired state

You can now just click to get zoom to the desired feature (it will be a left click)

[image]

Comment: That's pretty close to what I have in my head. 

What I'm trying to achieve exactly is that the geometries of a layer are displayed in the layer view window and I don't have to go through the attribute table first. However, splitting the layer into separate layers is not a solution....

Comment: @MaFo you mean you want to see the shape of the feature in the layers panel instead of the default square ?

Comment: Nope... i need to be able to select the single geometries in the layer view window without splitting the layer into single geometries. At the end it should look like the survace of google earth.