# Is there a functionality similar to ArcGIS' data driven pages for the QGIS map view?

Tags: qgis, mapcanvas

I know how to create an atlas for a QGIS layout, but what I'm looking for is a functionality for the map view which lets me use the features of a vector layer to zoom/pan to the next/last feature - just as I would do with ndata driven pages in an ArcGIS data frame. With other words, I'd like to have a control with let's say two buttons, a forward button that zooms the map view to the extent of the next feature in the reference layer and a back button that zooms to the last. Is there something like that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer for this question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438494/layer-filter-in-viewport/438499#438499, it should get you close to what you want

Comment: J.R, you're right - I hadn't remembered these buttons in the attribute table's form view. I'd still like to have **only** the back and forward buttons somewhere, but for what I have to do at the moment your method works just fine. Thanks!